# How do I make the output window's content always scroll to the bottom?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I came from PyCharm, and starting in VSCode, when I print a lot of content in the output window in VSCode, the output window will stay from the output of the last executed content, and I need to scroll all the way down to see the last part of the new output content.

Is there a way I can set it up so the output window will automatically go to the bottom of the output content? I have googled and searched stackoverflow, without any luck.

Here is some visual to show what I mean

[image]

I need to manually scroll down to see the last content

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your second screenshot, there is a padlock in the top right of your output window.  That enables/disables auto scrolling.

[image: padlock icon]

You currently have is disabled.  Try enabling it.

Comment: The padlock icon does it!

Comment: It is indeed the `padlock icon` that auto scrolls. Seems like such a niche thing to have it not auto scroll.